# How to set confluence data center cluster with different IP segment?

Tags: jira, confluence

I have two different IP segment servers:

Region 1:

- 10.2.100.1
- 10.2.100.2

Region 2:

- 10.2.200.1
- 10.2.200.2

They are using for 4 servers.

I want to use confluence data center product to join them together in one cluster. So I set these items in each server:

```
    <property name="confluence.cluster">true</property>
    <property name="confluence.cluster.home">/home/confluence/sharedhome</property>
    <property name="confluence.cluster.interface">bond0</property>
    <property name="confluence.cluster.join.type">tcp_ip</property>
    <property name="confluence.cluster.name">confluence</property>
    <property name="confluence.cluster.peers">10.2.100.1,10.2.100.2,10.2.200.1,10.2.200.2</property>
```

But I can see only two servers in the confluence dashboard in region 1 with segment IP `10.2.100`. If I switch to region 2 server cluster, I can see two nodes with segment IP `10.2.200`.

They didn't join together.

As official guide, if use `multicast IP` maybe another result:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/change-node-discovery-from-multicast-to-tcp-ip-or-aws-792297728.html

But how to set multicast IP in this case?

By the way, I got this error on node1 after node3 and node4 joined the cluster:

```
[Origin node: d62bd1bf listening on /10.2.100.1:5801] Clustered Confluence: Database is being updated by an instance which is not part of the current cluster. You should check network connections between cluster nodes, especially multicast traffic.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We avoid using multicast and instead hard-code the host names in each host's config files. Our network folk were not keen on enabling multicast